# Upper bound on the union of events using the assumption of independence

Tags: probability

Inclusion-exclusion states that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(A_i) -\sum_{i<j}\mathbb{P}(A_i\cap A_j)+\sum_{i<j<k}\mathbb{P}(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k) + \cdots +(-1)^{n-1} \sum_{i<...<n}\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right),
$$
In the special case where $P(A_i)=p$, and when the $k$-event intersection probabilities are all just $p^k$, for some $0 \leq p \leq 1$, this reduces to
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) =\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\binom n k p^k = 1 - (1-p)^n
$$
Is this also an upper bound on the original formula, **when we don't have this simple formula $p^k$ for the  $k$-event intersection probability**? That is, do we have $$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) \leq 1 - (1-p)^n$$
when $p^k$ now does not give the intersection probability of $k$ events. The r.h.s. is met with equality when $p^k$ does in fact give the intersection probabilities.

I also have $P(A_1)P(A_2) \leq P(A_1 \cap A_2)$, and so for any $k$-tuple of intersection. That is, $P(A)P(B)P(C) \leq P(A \cap B \cap C)$, and so on.

I can see that it does for two events $A_1$ and $A_2$, since $P(A_1)P(A_2) \leq P(A_1 \cap A_2)$, and so $$P(A_1 \cup A_2)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)-P(A_1 \cap A_2) \leq P(A_1)+P(A_2)-P(A_1)P(B_2)$$
Does this also work for more than two events?

Comment: Perhaps a look at the Bonferroni inequalities would be in order. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality#Bonferroni_inequalities

Comment: The formula certainly doesn't hold when the intersection probabilities are all zero, that is, when the events are mutually exclusive. Union can have probability $1$, which exceeds the right hand side.

Comment: Your $P(A)P(B)\le P(A\cap B)$ seems to be mistaken.

Comment: In my case, I have this, that the product of the two probabilities is going to be less than the probability of their intersection. I will clarify. Perhaps, then, it is true?

Comment: Basically, the question reduces to: is it true, in extension to the example above, that $P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3)=P(A_1)+P(A_2)+P(A_3)-P(A_1 \cap A_2)-P(A_1 \cap A_3)-P(A_2 \cap A_3) + P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) \leq P(A_1)+P(A_2)+P(A_3)-P(A_1)P(A_2)-P(A_1)P(A_3)-P(A_2)P(A_3)+P(A_1)P(A_2)P(A_3)$

Comment: ...and so on for all $k$-tuple unions.

Comment: OK, so, you are taking it as an *assumption* that $P(A)P(B)\le P(A\cap B)$? And you are asking what happens under this assumption? In that case, I was mistaken in my understanding of the question. But for three events, you could have $P(A\cup B\cup C)=1$, $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=1/2$, $P(A\cap B)=\cdots=1/4$, $P(A\cap B\cap C)=1/4$, and you wind up with the falsehood $1\le7/8$.

Comment: So, does that answer your question?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: My setting is where $A_i$  are each 3-hop paths between two vertices of the Erdos-Renyi random graph G(n,p). The probability of there union is "at least one 3-hop path exists". I think your comment above shows that only in the setting I am in is the bound potentially true, but is not true in general?

Comment: One thing, I don't just have $P(A)P(B) \leq P(A \cap B)$, but also $P(A)P(B)P(C) \leq P(A \cap B \cap C)$, and so on for all intersections (4, 5 events etc).

Comment: My example has $P(A)P(B)P(C)=1/8<1/4=P(A\cap B\cap C)$. I don't know how or whether my objection applies in your setting. I am sure that for the bound you want to hold you need some hypotheses beyond any you have stated.

Comment: What I have learned is that this is only a bound in the setting of probabilistic graph theory, where I am looking at the existence of a subgraph. It seems it is not true in general!